# VMware Workstation 9 Security Best Practice Guides

Tags: windows, virtualization

Could someone please be able point me in the direction of where I could find some best practice security guides for VMware Workstation 9 please? I've searched the VMware site and to say it's badly organised is an understatement! I've been able to find general setup guides but nothing with a specific focus on security.

I'm also wondering is there any best practice guides that I should follow when installing Windows 7 Professional and Windows Server 2008 R2 on VMware Workstation 9? I obviously will be implementing Microsofts recommended security best practices but I'd be very interested in any recommendations for virtualizing these operating systems.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that hardening guides are usually aimed at data-center virtualization products, rather than personal virtualization products like Workstation.

[VMWares security section](http://www.vmware.com/security/), for example, only has hardening guides for vSphere. These are worth looking at, as is the [SANS guide to hardening virtualization](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/analysts_program/vmware-guide-may-2010.pdf), but you will probably have to skip a lot of parts that don't apply.